# OpenGL: program organization

Tags: c++, opengl

I am starting to learn OpenGL. So far I am doing alright, the only problem is that I don't know exactly which is the "best" way to organize the program. For example, a lot of tutorials construct all of the code sequentially on the main() function, which I don't think is very nice. Others will build functions like render(), init(), and call them on the main() function.

Right now I am trying to mix things, I built a class to wrap GLFW and GLEW libraries, and I call them on the main(). Also I have init() and render() functions. The problem I am getting into is that I have to declare (GLuint program) as a global variable, which is not advisable. This is the only way I can get the render function to use also the variable.
Here is the code:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "GLWrapper.h"
#include "GLShader.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

GLuint program;

void renderer() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    float time = float(clock()) / float(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    GLint uniColor = glGetUniformLocation(program, "triangleColor");
    glUniform3f(uniColor, (sin(time * 4.0f) + 1.0f) / 2.0f, cos(time*2), 0.0f);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}

void init() {
    float vertices[] = {
        0.0f, 0.5f, // Vertex 1 (X, Y)
        0.5f, -0.5f, // Vertex 2 (X, Y)
       -0.5f, -0.5f  // Vertex 3 (X, Y)
    };
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo); // Generate 1 buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    program = LoadShader("Shader.vert", "Shader.frag");
    glUseProgram(program);

}

int main() {
    GLWrapper *glw = new GLWrapper(800, 600, "Ola Mundo!");

    glw->setRenderer(renderer);
    init();

    GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(program, "position");
    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);

    glw->glMainLoop();

    delete(glw);
    return 0;
}
```

So, I want to know If there is a better way of organizing this code (building a class perhaps?), because since I will be building bigger and bigger codes, I want them to be as organized as possible.

Hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Don't use classes if you don't need them. GLFW anf GLEW don't map into classes very well and OpenGL is practically impossible to wrap into OOP if you want to do it right. I know, that this sounds unbelievable, but I've been down that rabbit hole several times (3 times, trying it myself, then a couple of times consulting other people); save yourself a lot of gray hair by not trying to do it.

Comment: so what would be best? just use functions and global variables?

Comment: Functions: Yes. Global variables? No. Also classes are fine for encapsulating *data*. But OpenGL is a instruction (not data) driven API, GLFW is an application framework (if you were to put GLFW into a OOP wrapper, you'd have to force it to be a singleton, god object which is an OOP antipattern). And GLEW is just a dynamic loader for functions of OpenGL itself.

Comment: So what you should do is: Implement classes the encapsulate logically the data you want to bring to the screen, but not have those classes *implement* the interaction with OpenGL. If you want to be strictly OOP then encapsulate OpenGL operations in a visitor that can access the relevant classes and traverse the data structures. Do not implement a e.g., "OpenGL texture class"; instead implement a "texture image class" and a visitor can interface that texture to OpenGL.

Comment: that was a lot harder than I expected, haha, I still don't have much experience in OOP, but I will try to research a bit more on the subject

Comment: The main problem with OOP is, that newbies always suffer from a lot of fallacies and there are a lot of pitfalls to trip into, that prevent you from doing a clean OOP design. My recommendation is: Use plain structs to organize your data and functions that take those structs as a parameter. This avoids a lot of the headaches of creating a clean OOP design because you'll think in terms of which data belongs together and not which behavior.